# How to plot the result got by Gurobi?

Tags: python, gurobi

After I run the Gurobi model, I want to draw a scatter plot, where time is the x-axis and objective function value is the y-axis. How can I do it?

I notice there is a file named "gurobi" which has the values of time and objective function, but I want to plot it directly in Python.

Comment: Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have data set you can use Matplotlib library to plot any kind of plot. it would be more clear if you share your sample code. by the way here are simple example here:https://matplotlib.org/gallery/shapes_and_collections/scatter.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What I want to know is whether or not Gurobi has a method which can plot the improvement directly. Because if I plot the data by using Matplotlib, I need to modify the data set a lot.

Comment: As per my understanding,there is no direct way to plot results by Gurobi.I checked Gurobi if you require to illustrate changes it would use same way
[link]http://www.gurobi.com/resources/examples/example-models-overview 
 `A Python-only example that solves a financial portfolio optimization model, where the historical return data is stored using the pandas package and the result is plotted using the matplotlib package. It demonstrates the use of pandas, NumPy, and Matplotlib in conjunction with Gurobi.`

Comment: Thanks, it helps a lot!

Comment: Could you tell me where can I find the raw data named "portfolio.csv"?

Comment: You question is unclear! you initiate question and confirm that you have output data. By the way you can save values in csv format using `df.to_csv('output.csv')`, df is your Data Frame.